# Is it normal to have lots of ntoskrnl threads in system?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

I see a process named 'system' using between 4 and 12 % of my CPU (I7 8750H) regularly, even when I'm doing nothing. I learned that I could look in process explorer and I saw this:

[image]

Is it normal to have a list like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely normal.

You are looking at the stack of an executing process, and you see `ntoskrnl` on 
the top of the stack.

The `ntoskrnl` is the kernel of Windows, charged with running Windows itself
and  supplying low-level system services to all running processes.

This means that the process you are analyzing is currently doing a system call,
and is most probably in a wait state for some resource or some event, which is
why the stack is static. If it wasn't in a wait state, the top of the stack would
change more rapidly.

You can further see that you are probably watching a device driver issuing a
call to
[PoFxReportDevicePoweredOn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-pofxreportdevicepoweredon),
defined as:

> The PoFxReportDevicePoweredOn routine notifies the power management framework (PoFx) that the device completed the requested transition to the D0 (fully on) power state.

Meaning that the device is powered on and is waiting for requests.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds weird to me that at any given time 15 device drivers are transitioning to the "fulle on power state"?

Comment: You are looking at only one process, but with many threads. I don't know for which device, but for example a USB hub might spawn multiple threads for each physical port and service that it exposes. Examining all the available information might help to identify the process, but your question is basically answered.

Answer (score 1):

> "A **[kernel](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(computer_science))** is the central part of an operating system. It manages the
>   operations of the computer and the hardware - most notably memory and
>   CPU time." - Simple Wikipedia
>
> "**[NTOSKRNL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl.exe)** stands for NT Operating System Kernel" - Wikipedia

If you're always worried you may have something unwanted, a clean boot is a fast and easy start. [How to perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) *Also applies to Windows 10

This disables all services and startup items that were added post installation (factory installation). Once you are booted 'clean see if you still have the same activity.

It could be a 3rd party program you are running. [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/6zoxa9/ntoskmlexe_is_using_1520_cpu_when_idle/) user found HWmonitor was the culprit by following guide to use [Windows performance recorder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-performance-recorder/a1648e8c-50c7-4243-9f1d-4216385c7ff3).